# Why is my code Time Limit Exceeded while a really similar code is not (Leetcode 1249)?

Tags: c++, string

I am solving https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-remove-to-make-valid-parentheses/

**Description:** Given a string s of '(' , ')' and lowercase English characters.

Your task is to remove the minimum number of parentheses ( '(' or ')', in any positions ) so that the resulting parentheses string is valid and return any valid string.

I tried implementing a O(1) space solution that is

```
string minRemoveToMakeValid(string s) {
        string ans;
        string fa;
        int l=0;
        for(char c:s){
            if(c=='(') l++;
            else if(c==')'){
                if(l==0) continue;
                l--; 
            }
            ans = ans + c;
        }
        for(int i=ans.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
            if(ans[i]=='(' && l>0){
                l--;
                continue;
            }
            fa = fa + ans[i];
        }
        reverse(fa.begin(),fa.end());
        return fa; 
    }
```

But it throws Time Limit Exceeded.

A similar code is running and accepted and not throwing TLE and I'm unable to understand the difference which is causing this

```
string minRemoveToMakeValid(string s) {
        int open=0;
        string t;
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            if(s[i]=='(')open++;
            else if(s[i]==')')
            {
                if(open==0)continue;
                open--;
            }
            t+=s[i];
        }
        string ans;
        for(int i=t.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(t[i]=='(' && open>0)
            {
                open--;
                continue;
            }
            ans+=t[i];
        }
        reverse(ans.begin(),ans.end());
        return ans;
    }
```

Please help me understand and thanks for the helping me out.

Comment: btw it's not `O(1)` space solution

Comment: It makes it a lot harder to reason about this because both versions have extremely undescriptive variable names, and the only variable in common is `ans` which is used for different things in different versions.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I will now try to find out why += is better than the one I was using. @Bathsheba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a clever compiler, `+=` will probably be faster as it's simply concatenating a `char` to an existing `std::string` (there may well be a couple of allocations as string memory limits are reached but that won't occur on each call to `+=`).

The overloaded `+` operator for a `std::string` followed by an assignment back to self may well be causing a string copy.

A clever compiler ought to convert

```
fa = fa + ans[i];
```

to

```
fa += ans[i];
```

but the C++ standard does not *require* this.